# Open ThisWorkbook by password without prompt

Tags: excel, vba, passwords

This may sound like a wierd question but I need to get it done.
When ThisWorkbook is opened manually Open it with the password "1234" without prompting the user on opening using Excel VBA.

The prompt appears even when a password is suppost to be passed by vba.

The code is saved in ThisWorkbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False   
    Workbooks.Open fileName:=ThisWorkbook.FullName, Password:="1234", WriteResPassword:=""
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code tries to reopen the same file (reopen itself) (ThisWorkbook.FullName)

Create another excel file, copy the code in a module, and call it on open event:

```
    Private Sub OpenAnotherWorkBook()
        Application.EnableEvents = False   'disable Events
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="PathToPasswordProtectedFile.xlsm", Password:="1234", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnly:=False
        Application.EnableEvents = True    'enable Events
    End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  call OpenAnotherWorkBook()
End Sub
```

Change the "PathToPasswordProtectedFile.xlsm" to the fullpath of the protected file

Comment: I am trying to eliminate the need to enter a password in this workbook without using another file.

Comment: I think this is impossible because a password has been set to open it... and for the code to run the file must already be open.

Comment: As what I asked seams to be impossible I will accept your answer as solving this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As this is impossible by double-click on Excel doc, it will require password, by definition. Excel.exe has no command line password option neither.

You have Windows, so you have Powershell. Create a file `openexcel.ps1` with this content?

```
$path = (Get-Location).Path + "/myExcelDoc-password1234-without-prompt.xlsm"
$password = "1234"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($path, $false, $false, 5, $password)
$excel.Visible = $true
```

Then make a Windows shell link with command:

```
Powershell.exe openexcel.ps1
```

Double click on the shell link, password protected file will be opened without prompt for password.

Comment: Updated the question: When ThisWorkbook is opened manually...